# How can i read the RFH2 header in my process data or primary document in my business process when the input is a .rfh file

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, ibm-sterling

I am trying to read the RFH2 header as a part of project , where in i am using the WSMQ services in the sterling integrator like Open queue Get messages etc . 
The input i have used is a .rfh type file and i am not getting it in process data .

i need to get it in process data or primary document so that i can use xpath to get it in my get message service data

I have tried configuring MQRFH2 service but maybe i am missing something

In the RFH Util tool my RFH header comes in the ' other ' folder

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you have a properly constructed MQRFH2 message.  Also, what is an ".rfh" file?  Why don't you update your question with more information.  i.e. screen-shot the message in RFH Util.

You do know that there are 2 ways to get an MQRFH2 message from a queue.  You can get it as an MQRFH2 or as a message with named properties.